# Iterative formula for summing multiple values with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that does the following:

- References a cell to determine which tab/sheet to use
- Matches a column and row for each criteria and returns the value
- Sums the matched values

The closest I get is an index-match-match formula however there are several limitations including:

- If I add a new Column, then the formula won't pick up on it.

In the photo below is an example of what I'm after and the formula I'm using for now. The Criteria section A1:K12 is on a separate sheet.

On my master sheet is the Aircraft section A16:K17 with the columns and rows that form each criteria that I need to sum from the Criteria sheet. Row 1, 2, 3, etc are difference install options.

[image]

Comment: Excel or Google sheets? Do you know which you are using?

Comment: Please post the formula you've tried so far.

Comment: Indirect() can be used to include new columns - check on here.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Result in a separate sheet]

*Values are modified to easy verification.

Assume you put the sheetname and ranges in a way as shown in the first image.

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(B1&"!"&B5),INDIRECT(B1&"!"&B3),MATCH(INDIRECT(B1&"!"&B4),INDIRECT(B1&"!"&B2),0),FALSE),0)))
```

---

Updates:

Rules on the ranges:

- `Criteria "Column" range` should be the same as the starting row of `Criteria: section` (**2**:**2** & A**2**:K12)
- `Criteria: section` should starts from first column (**A**2:K12)

*You can add any columns (blank columns, or non-blank & non-criteria columns) at any position, if Column A is `Row 1, 2, 3,...`.

This also applies to rows, you could insert any blank or unrelated rows insides the `Criteria: section`.

By the way, may be `2:12` is better for `Criteria: section` is you are considering to add columns.

[image: *Modified values]

Comment: Legend @idfurw! Thank you so much - this is exactly what I was after.

One question I have is if this formula can be adapted to continue calculating if it runs into a column header that doesn't match? For example, I need to add a few columns before each Criteria column to calculate the correct figure that will go in the actual Column 1, 2, etc in the criteria section if that makes sense. If I add a column with a blank header or one with a header that doesn't match B16:16 then the formula doesn't continue calculating the remaining columns.

Comment: I have added rules on the criteria. Does it answer to you question? You may want to use formula or data validation to ensure the inputs are in a right way.